# What does 春闘集約 mean?

Tags: words, phrases

I found [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%98%A5%E9%97%98/) the definition of 春闘 as the annual spring wage bargaining round; the annual spring labor offensive.
And upon searching my electronic dictionary 集約 means intensive.

Can I assume that this phrase pertains to an action from a Japanese Labor Union discussing wage improvements for the union participants?

Is it limited to just wage or does this include all benefits of the employee?

Comment: What kind of electronic dictionary are you using?  「集約」 does **not** mean "intensive".  It is 「集約的」 that does.

Comment: 「集約」is used as a kind of suffix that means -intensive, e.g. 資本集約 = capital-intensive, but judging from the poster [here](http://www.densen.or.jp/news/link-files/zendensen783.pdf) I don't think that's what it means in this case...it seems like it means the collective bargaining effort of an aggregation of labour unions, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @l'electeur my bad, your correct. I'm using an Ex-Word Data plus4.
「集約」means put together not intensive.

Answer (score 1):

春闘 is the salary's discussion of blue-collar worker.

"春闘が集約しつつある" is correct sentence.